# Dropping the first row of a dataframe when looping through a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a function to loop through a list of dataframes containing tables I pulled from a website using pd.read_html. I want to drop the first row in each dataframe, and tried with the function I wrote below but it's not working. Does anyone know why?

```
for df in df_list:
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df.drop(df.index[0])

df_list[0]

    **Hospital/Location Specialty**
0   Hospital/Location   Specialty
1   Maimonides Med Ctr-NY Maimonides Med Ctr-NY Medicine-Preliminary Anesthesiology
2   Jacobi Med Ctr/Einstein-NY  Pediatrics
3   Jacobi Med Ctr/Einstein-NY  Pediatrics
4   Temple Univ Hosp-PA Internal Medicine
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign it back to df.

Like this,

```
df=df.drop(df.index[0])
```

It removed index 0 from my dataframe.  And the dataframe now starts at index 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assign it back

```
for idx, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df_list[idx]=df.drop(df.index[0])
```

Comment: what does enumerate do?

Comment: @gboge https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

why not use a comprehension

```
# test data:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0: ['col1', 'A', 'B'], 1: ['col2', '1', '2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({0: ['colA', 'a', 'b'], 1: ['colB', 'hello', 'goodbye']})
dfs = [df1, df2]

renamed = [d.rename(columns=df1.iloc[0]).drop(0) for d in dfs]

for df in renamed:
  print(df)
# outputs:
  col1 col2
1    A    1
2    B    2
  colA     colB
1    a    hello
2    b  goodbye
```